# Generics: generic class based on generic class

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a generic service that is based on a class with a generics based collection

```
public class GenericClass<T> {
   List<T> results;
   public List<T> getResults() {
    return results;
   }
}
```

Im just not sure how to create a service that is based on this GenericClass and has a concrete implementation of T. I would expect something like

```
public class ServiceManagerImpl<GenericClass<T>> implements ServiceManager<GenericClass<T>> {
    public GenericClass<T> getMyClass() {
    ...
    }
}
```

But the compiler doesn't like this. Any ideas how to do this?

Marc

Comment: Looks like Java to me, given the "implements" - but we don't have nearly enough information to answer it. What's ServiceManager? What error are you getting? Please provide a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: It's Java. I just get a syntax error on the first GenericClass<T>> after ServiceManagerImpl. The ServiceManager class as such is irrelevant. It's the generics I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2):

You are close... just pass the `T` through:

```
public class ServiceManagerImpl<T> implements ServiceManager<GenericClass<T>> {
    public GenericClass<T> getMyClass() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content between `<>` is called [**Type Parameters**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2), and `GenericClass<T>` is not a valid Type Parameter in declaration.

Quote from [java generic guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

> A generic class is defined with the following format:
>
> ```
> class name<T1, T2, ..., Tn> { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> The type parameter section, delimited by angle brackets (<>), follows the class name. It specifies the type parameters (also called type variables) T1, T2, ..., and Tn.

so, you need to use `GenericClass<T>` in implementation, not in declaration.

```
// declaration
public class ServiceManagerImpl<YourGenericType> implements ServiceManager<YourGenericType> {
    public YourGenericType getMyClass() {
    ...
    }
}

// implementation
ServiceManager<GenericClass<Object>> sm = new ServiceManagerImpl<GenericClass<Object>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ServiceManagerImpl<T extends GenericClass<T>> implements ServiceManager<T extends  GenericClass<T>> {
      public GenericClass<T> getMyClass() {
          ...
      }
}
```

Comment: this isn't quite the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following implementation that doesn't break the rules of JLS:

```
// ServiceManager.java
public interface ServiceManager<E, T extends GenericClass<E>> {
}

// ServiceManagerImpl.java
public class ServiceManagerImpl<E, T extends GenericClass<E>> implements ServiceManager<E, T> {
    public T getMyClass() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure my answer is legal , but it seems meet your requirement:

```
public class ServiceManagerImpl<T extends GenericClass> implements ServiceManager<T>
{
        @Override
        public T getMyclass() {
            //do your work here;
        }
}
```

Although it may have a `unchecked` warning when I declare this class , but this really does!

```
ServiceManager<GenericClass<Integer>> manager = new ServiceManagerImpl<GenericClass<Integer>>();//passed
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try likes this;

```
     public class ServiceManagerImpl<GenericClass<Object>> implements ServiceManager<GenericClass<Object>> {
          public GenericClass<Object> getMyClass() {
       ...
     }
```

}

You can replace Object with Integer or String or any data types as you likes.